# If $\vec{x}\neq 0$ and $\vec{y}$ are vectors in $\mathbb{R}^n$, show there is a linear transformation $T(\vec{x})=\vec{y}$

Tags: linear-algebra

I'm trying to prove the following:

If $\vec{x}\neq 0$ and $\vec{y}$ are vectors in $\mathbb{R}^n$, then show there is a linear transformation $T:\mathbb{R}^n\to\mathbb{R}^n$ such that $T(\vec{x})=\vec{y}$.

My lead is that I want to $T$ to be a matrix transformation. But after making $T$ equal a transformation $A$ such that $A(\vec{x})=\vec{y}$ I don't really know what to do.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3875067/linear-transformation-proof-for-rn-rn?r=SearchResults

Comment: That question was closed sadly and I don't understand the one answer that it has :(

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** Show that there is a linear transformation $f: \Bbb R^n \to \Bbb R$ such that $f(x) = 1$. Now, define $T$ by $T(v) = f(x)y$.

Comment: I'm sorry but I'm a first-year undergrad and I don't really understand

Comment: Can you think of any example of a linear transformation that takes a vector as its input and produces an output? Do you know what a dot-product is?